# How to recognize middle mouse release timing in Blender's PythonAPI

Tags: python, blender

I am making Blender addon.
I want to let Blender handle the viewpoint manipulation in modal mode, but I want to stop other modal mode operations while the middle mouse is being pressed. However, I cannot get the release event, so I cannot get the timing of when the middle mouse is released, and I do not know when the middle mouse is being pressed. How can I get the timing of when the middle mouse is pressed?

```py
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == "MIDDLEMOUSE":
            # cannot recognize release event
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
        elif event.type == "MOUSEMOVE":
            # some function
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

I did print debug of event and searched event API.

```py
print(event.type, event.value)
```

I expect recognizing the time dragging middle mouse.